# How to use HorizontalScrollView

Tags: horizontalscrollview

Hey guys I am new to android designing phase hope you people can help me  with the problem.I created 4 HorizontalScrollView but i am able to access(Move) only the last view.I am not able to access(Move) 1st 2nd and 3rd HorizontalScrollView.I have provided the code below for your reference

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff4952"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="8dp"

                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="8dp"

                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                >


            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="8dp"

                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/aaaa" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: can you share screen short?